# Make a cell blink in Excel (macro within a macro)

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make a cell "Z1" blink if value in X1 is above 999. I have made 2 modules, one to sound an alarm if value is above 999 and Z1 has a counter to check how many times have value been above 999. Now I need Z1 to blink whenever there is an increase in the counter or X1 value > 999 and revert to its original state. Only stuck in the part where it does not blink.

Below is my code, where am I wrong.

```
Private BlnAboveHundred1K As Boolean
Private IntCounter1K As Integer

Function TargetCounterROW1COL1(RngMeasure As Range)
    
   If RngMeasure.Value > 999 Then
        If BlnAboveHundred1K = False Then
            IntCounter1K = IntCounter1K + 1
           
            If Sheets("WorkArea").CommandButton14.Caption = "On" Then
            Call PlaySound("c:\windows\media\Alert4.wav", _
            0, SND_ASYNC Or SND_FILENAME)

            Call StartBlink

            End If
            
        BlnAboveHundred1K = True
        Else
        BlnAboveHundred1K = True
        'IntCounter = 0
    End If
Else
    BlnAboveHundred1K = False
End If

TargetCounterROW1COL1 = IntCounter1K

End Function
```

Cell Blink Module Below

```
Private IntBlinkCounter As Integer
Sub StartBlink()

Dim xCell As Range

Dim xTime As Variant
On Error Resume Next
Set xCell = Range("WorkArea!Z11")
On Error Resume Next

If xCell.Font.Color = vbRed Then
xCell.Font.Color = vbWhite
Else
xCell.Font.Color = vbRed

End If
xTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

IntBlinkCounter = IntBlinkCounter + 1
If IntBlinkCounter < 5 Then
Application.OnTime xTime, "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!StartBlink", , True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Leaving away the `,,True` seems to solve the problem. I found this by looking at [this](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Application.OnTime_en.html)

Comment: `i` does absolutely nothing in `StartBlink` macro. All rows containing `i` can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I commented out some lines and now blinking macro works for me:

```
Sub StartBlink()
  Dim xCell As Range
  'Dim i As Integer
  Dim xTime As Variant
  'On Error Resume Next
  Set xCell = Range("WorkArea!Z1")
  'On Error Resume Next
  If xCell.Font.Color = vbRed Then
      xCell.Font.Color = vbWhite
  Else
      xCell.Font.Color = vbRed
  End If
  xTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
  'i = i + 1
  Application.OnTime xTime, "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!StartBlink", , True
  'If i = 6 Then i = 0
  'Application.OnTime xTime, "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!StartBlink", , False
End Sub
```

---

This line *adds* the macro to the schedule:
`Application.OnTime xTime, "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!StartBlink", , True`
While another line  *removes* the macro from the schedule:
`Application.OnTime xTime, "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!StartBlink", , False`
Basically, you add it and instantly remove it. This is why it never actually started.

---

If it does not help, try changing `Call StartBlink` to something like

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!StartBlink", , True
```

---

In order to stop blinking after several blinks you will need two thigs.

First, *outside* the blinking macro, at the very top of the module, create a blinks count variable, e.g.:
`Private IntBlinkCounter As Integer`

Second, inside the `StartBlink` macro, change the line
`Application.OnTime xTime, "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!StartBlink", , True`
with

```
IntBlinkCounter = IntBlinkCounter + 1
If IntBlinkCounter < 5 Then
    Application.OnTime xTime, "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!StartBlink", , True
End If
```

Comment: I only want this blinking run for only 5 seconds and then stop, that is why i included the "i"

Comment: The blinking does work, but it just keeps going on, how can i stop this say after 5 seconds, what changes need to be done here?

Comment: @notacoder - I have complemented the answer

Comment: This doesnt seem to work. did exactly as directed by u

Comment: changed the code above in my original code,pls check

Comment: `Private IntBlinkCounter As Integer` should be added at the top, not in the middle - together with other `Private` variables.

Comment: Did exactly that if you check the code Added it right above the Sub StartBlink()

Comment: I meant at the top of the module, which is very top

Comment: At the top of the module? If you see there are actually two modules, i added it right below the StartBlink Module, i dont think adding this on the top Function Module will make any difference, changed the code, still no go

Comment: You talk about the Sub (a.k.a. macro or routine). The module is this whole window/ canvas. Put it next to `Private IntCounter1K As Integer`